# Why does $ \frac{1 + |u|^p}{1 + |u|} \in L^{N/2}_{loc}(\Omega) $?

Tags: integration, inequality, lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $u \in H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ is an open set and $p < 2^* -1$. Why does it hold that
$$
\frac{1 + |u|^p}{1 + |u|} \in L^{N/2}_{loc}(\Omega) \quad ?
$$

Of course, if $\omega \subset \Omega$ is compact then
$$
\int_\omega \left(\frac{1 + |u|^p}{1 + |u|}\right)^{N/2} \leq \int_\omega (1 + |u|^p)^{N/2} \leq \int_\omega (1 + |u|^p)^N \leq 2^N \int_\omega (1 + |u|^{pN}).
$$
But $pN$ may be greater then $2^*$, and in this case we don't know if $u \in L^{pN}(\omega)$.

Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Context: I am trying to understand Struwe's presentation of the Brezis-Kato regularity argument.

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bound is bad when $|u|$ is big. Try using:
$$ \frac{1 + |u|^p}{1 + |u|} \leq {1 + |u|^{p-1}} $$
which can be proved multiplying both LHS and RHS by ${1 + |u|}$.

Comment: @DaniloGregorin
Not actually, if $\lvert u \rvert = 0$ you wrote $0/0$.

Comment: Please, is the following line of thought correct?
$$
\frac{1 + |u|^p}{1 + |u|} = \frac{1}{1 + |u|} + \frac{|u|^p}{1 + |u|} \leq 1 + \frac{|u|^p}{|u|}
$$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much, it is clear now. However, couldn't we still get $(p - 1)N > 2^*$?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin It's a direct calculation. Let me know if you want me to write down the details

Comment: Got this. Many thanks.